# Pair term from string array using window size in Java

Tags: java

Is there a way to take the following string array :

"The, quick, brown, fox, jumps, over"

and generate the following list using Java by:

"the quick", "the brown", "quick the", "quick brown", "quick fox", "brown the", "brown quick", "brown fox", "brown jump", "fox quick", "fox brown", "fox jumps", "fox over".....

I use a window of text/ window size = 2. How can I pair term from this string array?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? Where did it fail?

Comment: I have not idea basic algo for this. I want get pair term for term co-occurence

Comment: okayy, for the next question :) @robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code for getting the pairs out of string array.

```
public class Scratch {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int windowSize = 2;
    String[] tokens = {"The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over"};
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i - windowSize; j <= i + windowSize; j++) {
            if (j >= 0 && j< tokens.length && i != j) {
                System.out.println(tokens[i] + " " + tokens[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}